# symfony 2.3 + liip + gaufrette = create thumb of a remote image (by url)

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle, gaufrette

I get an old Symfony 2.3 project.
I never use Symfony before ( i'm in Angularjs ) so it is a little hard.

What i want to do : i need to tweak the project so i can display thumb of local image or remote image ( i will get the full url of already uploaded images), the thumb should be created in local cache.

Liip image bundle already used in the project with filters.
I installed KnpGaufretteBundle with composer.

1.in `services.yml`

```
 services:
    acme.liip_imagine.binary.loader.stream.profile_photos:
        class: "%liip_imagine.binary.loader.stream.class%"
        arguments:
            - 'gaufrette://profile_photos/'
        tags:
            - { name: 'liip_imagine.binary.loader', loader: 'stream.profile_photos' }
```

2.in `config.yml`

```
liip_imagine:
    #cache_clearer: false
    #cache_mkdir_mode: 0777
    loaders:
        stream.profile_photos:
            stream:
                wrapper: gaufrette://profile_photos
    filter_sets:
        url_thumb:
            data_loader: stream.profile_photos
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [100, 100], mode: outbound }
```

3.in view.twig

```
// If i display directly the img it works
{% set img = row.path %}
<a href="{{ img }}" class="grouped_elements" rel="group" title="{{ row.copyright }}">
    <img src="{{ img  }}" width="100px" alt="{{ img }}" border="0" />
</a>

// but i get an error with this : 
{% set imgspe = row.path|basename %}
{% set img = ['uploads/'~module.uploaddir~'/', imgspe]|join('') %}
<a href="{{ asset(img) }}" class="grouped_elements" rel="group" title="{{ row.copyright }}">
    <img src="{{ asset(img) | imagine_filter('url_thumb') }}" alt="{{ imgspe }}" border="0" />
</a>
```

The error :

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://publish.test/app_dev.php/media/cache/url_thumb/http://www.jump-voyage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Google-Images-4.jpg

'Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "Source image not found." at /var/www/test/publishv2/vendor/liip/imagine-bundle/Liip/ImagineBundle/Binary/Loader/StreamLoader.php line 55'
```

So the url is not good because it is local path + url path concatenation

What can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I do it manually without liip/gaufrette.

I do it manually :

```
<?php
/*
 * étapes
 *
 * si image existe
 *      on la retourne
 *
 * sinon
 *      créer le chemin complet
 *      créer la vignette
 *      retourner la vignette
 *
 * chemin ou sont stocké les images : media/cache_url_thumb/thumb_{{w}}_{{h}}
 *
 */

// retourne le contenu d'une image
function sendimg($path,$filename){
    $contents = file_get_contents($path.$filename);
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo $contents;
}

/**
 * crée une miniature dans le dossier $updir
 * @param $updir    : dossier ou crée la miniature
 * @param $img      : image orignale
 * @param $finalimg : image finale
 * @param $width
 * @param $height
 */
function makeThumbnails($updir, $img, $finalimg,$width=134, $height=189)
{
    $thumbnail_width = $width;
    $thumbnail_height = $height;
    $arr_image_details = getimagesize("$updir" . "$img");
    // cl($arr_image_details);
    $original_width = $arr_image_details[0];
    $original_height = $arr_image_details[1];
    if ($original_width > $original_height) {
        $new_width = $thumbnail_width;
        $new_height = intval($original_height * $new_width / $original_width);
    } else {
        $new_height = $thumbnail_height;
        $new_width = intval($original_width * $new_height / $original_height);
    }
    $dest_x = intval(($thumbnail_width - $new_width) / 2);
    $dest_y = intval(($thumbnail_height - $new_height) / 2);
    if ($arr_image_details[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
        $imgt = "ImageGIF";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromGIF";
    }
    if ($arr_image_details[2] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        $imgt = "ImageJPEG";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromJPEG";
    }
    if ($arr_image_details[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        $imgt = "ImagePNG";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromPNG";
    }
    if ($imgt) {
        $old_image = $imgcreatefrom("$updir" . "$img");
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);
        imagecopyresized($new_image, $old_image, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $original_width, $original_height);
        $imgt($new_image, "$updir" . $finalimg);
    }
}

//crypte le nom pour éviter les erreurs avec caractères bizarre dans nom fichiers
function toMd5($string){
    return md5($string);
}


// créer un dossier si il n'éxiste pas
function createDir($path){
    if (!is_dir($path)) {
        if (!mkdir("$path", 0777,true)) {
            die('Echec lors de la création du repertoire $path pour les thumb images distantes...');
        }
    }
}


$originalSrc = $_GET["src"];
$filename = toMd5($originalSrc);
$path = 'media/cache_url_thumb/'."thumb_".$_GET["width"]."_".$_GET["height"]."/";
$path .=  substr($filename,0,3) . "/";

// vérifier si image existe
if(file_exists($path.$filename)){
    sendimg($path,$filename);
}else{
    // l'image n'existe pas
    createDir($path);
    $tmpfilename = 'original_'.$filename;
    copy( $originalSrc , $path.$tmpfilename);
    makeThumbnails($path ,$tmpfilename,$filename,$_GET["width"],$_GET["height"]);
    unlink($path.$tmpfilename);
    sendimg($path,$filename);
}
?>
```

and the twig :

```
<a href="{{ img }}" class="grouped_elements" rel="group" title="{{ row.copyright }}">
    <img src="/geturlimage.php?src={{ img |url_encode }}&width=100&height=100" alt="{{ img }}" border="0" />
</a>
```